# Button to URL in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url, button

I have no knowledge of jquery but I am using a plugin that I am trying to get to work. It is a social media floating plugin and I am trying to change the URLs. There is no HTML in the documents only css and js. Below is a snippet from the js file:

```
social_count.pinterest = function () {
    count_url = "http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=?&url="+url
    $.getJSON(count_url, function (response) {
            $('.count.pinterest').html(response.count)
    });
    return 0;
};
```

I want the URL to go to www.google.com when a visitor clicks the respective social media icon.There are several URLs, most of which look the same. How do I change the URLs to go to google without affecting the counters?

A sample of a changed link that I can apply to all buttons is most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Another issue found with your source. Try setting the callback parameter `callback=something` or remove it otherwise you will get **`{"error":"Invalid callback, use only letters, numbers, square brackets, underscores, and periods."}`**

Comment: All this code does is call pinterest and see how many times a URL has been shared/pinned, then probably updates a little "bubble" on your site with that count. This doesn't forward anyone anywhere. If you want it so that when a person clicks on a social media icon that they're sent to google.com or wherever, you need to post those icons.

Comment: Thanks Michael. How do I post the icons? Sorry I know nothing of jquery or js

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a link.

Answer (score -1):

Write click event on `<button>` tag by providing `class name` to each social media `<button>` tag in your html, So when user clicks on the button below click event will be triggered and redirects the user to `www.google.com`.

Try with below code:

```
$(".social_media_btn").on('click', function(){
   window.location.href = "www.google.com"
})
```

here `social_media_btn` is the example `<button>` tag class name

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you. I just removed the count and added the URL

Comment: You have a syntax error..... `'click,` missing the single quote at the end of `click`

Comment: sorry, I have n't see